# Mysql OR performance Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization, query-performance

I am using `OR` in mysql query to check different values at same time, I found results are coming very slow and here I am joining two tables also, I am unable to check which is taking long time.

Query here:

```
select l.*, l.category as lid
FROM listings AS l
LEFT JOIN listprices as pr ON pr.product_id=l.id 
where (pr.price >= 100 AND pr.price <= 1000) 
  OR (pr.price >= 1001 AND pr.price <= 5000) 
OR  (pr.price >= 5001 AND pr.price <= 10000) 
 order by pr.price ASC
```

query working fine but results taking too much time.  If any other alternative to get fast. I have heard  OR taking much time to execute results.

Comment: Side note, You have to put some parentheses to separate the `OR` from `AND` like this `id 
where (pr.price >= 100 AND pr.price <= 1000)
   OR (pr.price >= 1001 AND pr.price <= 5000)
   OR (pr.price >= 5001 AND pr.price <= 10000)`

Comment: yes parentheses I forgot.

Comment: Wait a minute...is your current `WHERE` clause contrived?  It is basically saying you want `pr.price >= 100` AND `pr.price <= 10000`.

Comment: yes I am looking for where pr.price >= 100 AND pr.price <= 10000

Comment: Not related to your question, but filtering on listprices in the where clause turns your left join to an inner join.  If you really want listings with no prices, which sounds odd, you have to filter in the join.

Comment: Assuming your `price` column is indexed, the `or` condition is not going to use index and you may need to change it and use `union` with each query as its own condition.

Comment: No one can answer your question until you tell us what the results from 'EXPLAIN' and also provide some indication about what your tables look like

Comment: ....and provide an explanation of why you think the performance is a result of using 'OR' in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't handle OR clauses very well. (Correctly, but slowly.) In your case it seems like the presence of your sequence of OR clauses is defeating the use of your index on `listprices.price`. That will make your performance stink. Let's try to refactor this query to avoid that sequence of OR clauses.

Notice that you have a `LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x.column ...` pattern in your query. That converts your `LEFT JOIN` to an inner `JOIN`.

First, let's do a subquery to get a list of `listprices.product_id` values with matching prices. That goes like this:

```
SELECT price, product_id FROM listprices pr WHERE pr.price >= 100 AND pr.price <= 1000
UNION
SELECT price, product_id FROM listprices pr WHERE pr.price >= 1001 AND pr.price <= 5000
UNION
SELECT price, product_id FROM listprices pr WHERE pr.price >= 5001 AND pr.price <= 10000
```

These three queries (unioned together) each can be made very fast by a compound index on `price, product_id`.  You'd be wise to test this query to ensure it's giving the result you want.

Then you will use this query as a subquery; that is, as if it were itself a table:

```
select l.*, l.category as lid
  FROM listings AS l
  JOIN (
       SELECT price, product_id FROM listprices pr WHERE pr.price >= 100 AND pr.price <= 1000
       UNION
       SELECT price, product_id FROM listprices pr WHERE pr.price >= 1001 AND pr.price <= 5000
       UNION
       SELECT price, product_id FROM listprices pr WHERE pr.price >= 5001 AND pr.price <= 10000
       ) pr ON pr.product_id = l.id
 order by pr.price ASC
```

This should get you the result you want more quickly.

Comment: Thank You Jones. Working Fast.